# How can I change my checkbox to radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, htmlextensions

So, I want to change my checkbox, that has checked and unchecked state to radio buttons that say, Yes (checked) or No (unchecked).

Here's what I did for the checkbox:

In my view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxUi("PerpendicularCheckbox",@H.GetString("IsPerpendicular"), null, new { style = "margin-right:10px", @class = "type-style-paragraph" })
```

js:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=PerpendicularCheckbox]').on({
                "change": function () {
                    if (getUpdate()) {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if (($this).is(':checked'))
                            $("ul li button").click();
                    }
                }
            });

            if (!Perpendicular) {                
                $("#PerpendicularCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
            }
            else {               
                $("#PerpendicularCheckbox").prop("checked", true);
            }
```

I was wondering what would I need to change it to radio buttons, yes and no options, using html extension in asp.net mvc?

EDIT:

My loosy attempt at radio buttons:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonForUi("PerpendicularCheckbox",@H.GetString("IsPerpendicular"), null, new { style = "margin-right:10px", @class = "type-style-paragraph" })



 $('input:radio[name=PerpendicularCheckbox]').on({
                    "change": function () {
                        if (getUpdate()) {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (($this).is(':checked'))
                                $("ul li button").click();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

RadioButtonForUi :

```
 public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForUi<TModel, TProperty>(
          this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
          string name,
          bool IsEnable,
          bool IsChecked,
          object onchange = null,
          string className = "",
          bool isRequreid = true

        ) {etc.....}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493075(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes something like that but I just want to know how to use @html.radiobutton with choices of yes and no for the above checkbox.

Comment: so why not use @Html.RadioButtonFor if you need radio button?!

Comment: I get errors, so I'm not sure if i'm doing it right?

Comment: Like this error:  The type arguments for method 'H.HtmlExtensions.RadioButtonForUi<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, string, bool, bool, object, string, bool)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: Can you please post THAT code. It sounds like youa re on the right track.

Comment: See edit. I didn't change too much. I would like see an example however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested sample:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SaleOfPropertyPurchase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SaleOfPropertyPurchase, true, new { id = "SaleOfPropertyPurchase-true" }) Yes
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SaleOfPropertyPurchase, false, new { id = "SaleOfPropertyPurchase-false" }) No
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SaleOfPropertyPurchase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is some sample jquery that reacts to the radio button click, and also sets up initial display on the form:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#CurrentPropertyOwner-true').on('change', function () {
            $('#CurrentProperty').show();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#CurrentPropertyOwner-false').on('change', function () {
            $('#CurrentProperty').hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ischecked = $('#CurrentPropertyOwner-true').is(':checked')
        if (ischecked == true) {
            $('#CurrentProperty').show();
        }
        var ischecked = $('#CurrentPropertyOwner-false').is(':checked')
        if (ischecked == true) {
            $('#CurrentProperty').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render two radio buttons for the property, one with the value of "True" and the other with the value of "False" so the selected value can be bound to a `boolean` value

You custom html helper would need to be

```
namespace YourAssembly.Html
{
  public static class MyHelpers
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString BooleanButtonsFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
    {
      ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
      string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
      StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
      // Yes button
      string id = string.Format("{0}-yes", name);
      html.Append(helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, "True", new { id = id }));
      html.Append(helper.Label(id, "Yes"));
      // No button
      id = string.Format("{0}-no", name);
      html.Append(helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, "False", new { id = id }));
      html.Append(helper.Label(id, "No"));
      // enclode in a div for easier styling with css
      TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
      div.AddCssClass("radiobuttongroup");
      div.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(div.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

then add a reference to the `<namespaces>` section of web.config

```
<add namespace="YourAssembly.Html "/>
```

and use it in the view

```
@Html.BooleanButtonsFor(m => m.YourBoolProperty)
```